# how can i get user's favorite video of youtube using JSONHTTPClient?

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am working on the youtube app. i want to get users favourite video using JSON.

**I am using following code**

```
  NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%@/favorites",auth.userEmail];
     [JSONHTTPClient getJSONFromURLWithString: strURl
                                      completion:^(NSDictionary *json, JSONModelError *err) {

                                      if (err) {
                                          HideProgress();

                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                      message:@"Please try different keywords or try again later"
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                                          return;
                                      }

                                      //initialize the models
                                      videos = [VideoModel arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries:
                                                json[@"feed"][@"entry"]
                                                ];
                                      if (videos) {
                                          //show the videos
                                          [self showVideos];
                                      } else {
                                          HideProgress();

                                          [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                                      message:@"Please try different keywords or try again later"
                                                                     delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                            otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
                                      }
                                  }];

}
```

But I am getting error that says:`Error Domain=JSONModelErrorDomain Code=1 "Bad network response." UserInfo=0x923d8a0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Bad network response.}`

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: or, to be more precise (if you type the URL directly into a browser): "`Invalid value for parameter: username`"

Comment: so how can i get  favorite video list of user. I have read the youtube query parameter but i am not able to get it.